# OpenCV Android CamShift Assertion failed error

Tags: java, opencv, android

I am trying to implement an object tracking application on android using the OpenCV camShift function. I am using the camera of my android tablet to get an image frame. I define a rectangle of the space I want to track inside the image frame. Afterwards I pass those two values over to the Video.Camshift function as well as a terminal criteria. After I start the application I get an:

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed –error

Here is the relevant Code:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

     Mat scene = inputFrame.rgba();

     if(trackingFrame == null){
          trackingFrame = new Rect(scene.cols()/2,scene.rows()/2,50,50);
     }
     System.out.println(trackingFrame.size().toString());
     RotatedRect box =Video.CamShift(scene, trackingFrame, new TermCriteria(TermCriteria.EPS,10,1)); 
     trackingFrame = box.boundingRect();
     Point pt1 =new Point(trackingFrame.x,trackingFrame.y);
     Point pt2 =new Point(trackingFrame.x+trackingFrame.width,trackingFrame.y+trackingFrame.height);
     Scalar RED = new Scalar(255,0,0);
     Imgproc.rectangle(scene, pt1, pt2, RED);
     return scene;
 }
```

And this is the error I get:

```
E/cv::error()(19177): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (cn == 1) in int cv::meanShift(cv::InputArray, cv::Rect&, cv::TermCriteria), file /home/maksim/workspace/android-pack/opencv/modules/video/src/camshift.cpp, line 59
E/org.opencv.video(19177): video::CamShift_10() caught cv::Exception: /home/maksim/workspace/android-pack/opencv/modules/video/src/camshift.cpp:59: error: (-215) cn == 1 in function int cv::meanShift(cv::InputArray, cv::Rect&, cv::TermCriteria)
W/dalvikvm(19177): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x42f05500)
E/AndroidRuntime(19177): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8274
E/AndroidRuntime(19177): CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: /home/maksim/workspace/android-pack/opencv/modules/video/src/camshift.cpp:59: error: (-215) cn == 1 in function int cv::meanShift(cv::InputArray, cv::Rect&, cv::TermCriteria)
```

I do not really understand what the problem is, since the error messages do not say anything specific. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score -1):

Ok, i found my mistake.
Instead of using the camera input, i first had to:

- select the Object inside the picture I want to track
- make a histogram of that picture with `calcHist`
- use that histogram for the `calcBackProject` function
- use the output of the `calcBackProject` in the `Video.CamShift`-function

Comment: if the  problem is solved  ,please edit the answer with the complete solved code.